# How to install composer in ubuntu for using omnipay?

Tags: php, codeigniter, ubuntu, omnipay

I am working to implement online payment system in codeigniter. So, I am using omnipay with codeigniter. For this reason, I have to install composer.

I am trying several times to install composer in ubuntu 12.04. But I have failed.
My terminal display an error as,

```
 Could not create file /var/www/tcm/composer.phar: fopen(/var/www/tcm/composer.phar):
 failed to open stream: Permission denied
 Download failed: fopen(/var/www/tcm/composer.phar): failed to open stream: Permission 
 denied fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

Could you suggest me, How can I solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution. I have to change the directory file permission to 777. Now it is ok.